# Getting data from two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to get data from two different table and put into on statement but its not working. This is what I am looking to get as a complete statement: I want the query to display the dname, loc, Number of People. I am having a problems with the sub query.

```
 SQL> select dname, loc from dept where ename in (count(ename) AS Number_of_People  from emp);
select dname, loc from dept where ename in (count(ename) AS Number_of_People from emp)
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here


SQL>
```

Table emp

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate, deptno from emp;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE      DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT 17-NOV-81         10
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   01-MAY-81         30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER   09-JUN-81         10
  7566 JONES      MANAGER   02-APR-81         20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  28-SEP-81         30
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-81         30
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  08-SEP-81         30
  7900 JAMES      CLERK     03-DEC-81         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN  22-FEB-81         30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST   03-DEC-81         20
  7369 SMITH      CLERK     17-DEC-80         20

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE      DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   09-DEC-82         20
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK     12-JAN-83         20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK     23-JAN-82         10

 14 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

Table dept

```
 SQL> select * from dept;

 DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
  ---------- -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

   SQL>
```

Comment: How do you know which department a person works in?   Not clear in your tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
select dname, loc, (select count(ename) from emp where DEPTNO = dept.deptno) as Number_of_people 
from dept;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but something that sticks out is that you probably need to use a `select` in your subquery.  Try:

```
select dname, loc 
from dept 
where ename in (select count(ename) AS Number_of_People  from emp);
```

Comment: SQL> select dname, loc  from dept  where ename in (select count(ename) AS Number_of_People  from emp);
select dname, loc  from dept  where ename in (select count(ename) AS Number_of_People  from emp)
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ENAME": invalid identifier

Comment: Okay, then what is `ename` and what was it doing there in the first place?

Comment: ename is the name of the employee. As for its doing there I am not 100% sure if that was correct I was asking the question of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, `count(column)` gives a number.  `ename` is a string.  Trying to look for a string in a list of numbers won't get you what you want.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select dept.dname, dept.loc,count(*) 
from emp 
join dept on emp.deptNo=dept.deptno
group by dept.dname,dept.loc
```